# Is there a way to subset data based on row names for a legend in a lineplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

This is a sample of the structure of my data:

| Site. | MOD. | date | GPP.daily | ER.daily |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CB05 | DIS | 2019-07-08 | 0.1787. | 0.63 |
| CB05 | DIS | 2019-07-09 | 0.1797. | 0.61 |
| CB05 | NO.DIS | 2019-07-08 | 0.1277. | 0.63 |
| CB05 | NO.DIS | 2019-07-09 | 0.1577. | 0.64 |
| CB04 | DIS | 2019-07-08 | 0.1777. | 0.60 |
| CB04 | DIS | 2019-07-09 | 0.1777. | 0.66 |
| CB04 | NO.DIS | 2019-07-08 | 0.1247. | 0.63 |
| CB04 | NO.DIS | 2019-07-09 | 0.1587. | 0.64 |

I have multiple unique sites (CB04-CB25), 2 versions of MOD, and about 40 days of data for each Site/MOD combination.

I was wanting to plot my data as a time series. I wanted a separate line for each Site-MOD combination on the same graph, with a legend. I.e., CB04-DIS, CB05-DIS, CB05-NO.DIS will all have separate lines on the graph (using geom_point in ggplot2).

I have tried subsetting the data but because I have so much data this ends up being very time-consuming. I figure there's a simpler way to do this I just haven't found it yet.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is perfect, and thank you for the gghighlight suggestion!! Worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- 
dt %>% 
  mutate(SiteMod = paste0(Site., "-",MOD.),
         date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = GPP.daily) ) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = SiteMod))
p
```

[image]

But if you have so many combinations of unique sites you may want to focus on some lines with `gghighlight()` from the `gghighlight` package.

```r
p +
gghighlight::gghighlight(dt$MOD. == "DIS")
#> Warning: Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
#> Falling back to ungrouped filter operation...
#> label_key: SiteMod
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>